# c# website login to website

Tags: c#, web

I'm relatively new to using c#. Now I'm doing a application about login to a webside automaticlly and collect the data! I have searched some information about this and I know that firstly I must post my account and password to the webside. For example:

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl); 
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
req.Method = "POST"; 
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
req.ContentLength = bytes.Length; 
using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream()) 
{
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

formUrl is the url which I must post the acount and password information to and the formParams is the information of acount and password.   Now the quetion is :  How to get the formUrl.

Here is some of my webside html code:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="/cn/LogForm.aspx" onsubmit="return CheckLogin(this);">
<input type="hidden" name="backurl" value="/cn/assistant.aspx"/>
<table width="262" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="60" height="30" align="center">用户名：</td>
        <td width="130"><input name="Username" type="text" class="border-login" tabindex=1 /></td>        "
```

The webside I want to login is "http://www.cantonfair.org.cn/cn/"

Answer (score 3):

Use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/), Addon for firefox to find out the posting URL, by opening the page in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just the ACTION path? Or am I missing something?

```
action="/cn/LogForm.aspx"
```

formURL is http://www.cantonfair.org.cn/cn/LogForm.aspx